# Dropdown content image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an image I was wondering how do I make it into a dropdown container.

Im new to this any help

```css
.fa-chevron-circle-down {
  position: absolute;
  right: 26%;
  top: 28px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 25px; cursor: pointer;"></i>
```

Comment: In this context: What is, according to you, a dropdown container? A button you press to get a dropdown menu, perhaps?

Comment: where a user can hover the button then it shows a small list of items to click

Comment: So you need to make a list of items and show it when hovering over your 'dropdown container'.

Comment: Yes! I need it.

Comment: Well, get started, so far you've hardly got anything. Whether your 'dropdown container' is an nice icon or something else is not really relevant.

Comment: why create a snippet if you cant get it to run correctly

Comment: well how can I do one

Comment: css, because js might be too difficult for you at the moment. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here's an example. The button and the menu are both in a container. The menu is hidden by css, but shown when you are hovering over the container. This way hovering over the button shows the menu and it is hidden when the mouse exits the menu.

You really need to do more research - I'm downvoting the question.

```css
#menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 28px;
  right: 26%;
}

.fa-chevron-circle-down {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 22px;
  height:28px;
}

ul {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 28px;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: none;
}

li {
  padding: 5px;
}

li:nth-of-type(even) {
  background: #ddd;  
}
li:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background: #eee;  
}

#menu:hover ul {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="menu">
  <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 25px; cursor: pointer;"></i>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">This</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Is</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Approach</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```